# Debugging why react-native release build crushes and debug one works fine

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I was working in Debug mode where everything seemed fine, however when I build my app to TestFlight (i.e. release build) it crashed at LaunchScreen.

After some time and debugging I narrowed issue down to following code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Subscribe } from 'unstated'

const getStoreAsProps = (storeArr) => {
  const storeProps = {}
  storeArr.map(value => (storeProps[value.constructor.name] = value))
  return storeProps
}

const withStore = (...args) => (Element) => () => (
  <Subscribe to={[...args]}>{(...args) => <Element {...getStoreAsProps(args)} />}</Subscribe>
)

export default withStore
```

The way this works is as follows

```
import React from "react"
import { Text } from "react-native"
import AuthStore from "./store/Auth"
import RouterStore from "./store/Router"
import withStore from "./store"

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
  const {AuthStore, RouterStore} = this.props
  return <Text>{AuthStore.state.username} {RouterStore.state.pathname}</Text>
  }
}

export default withStore(AuthStore, RouterStore)(MyComponent)
```

So essentially `withStore` is a higher order component that can take in any number of arguments, in this case `Stores` and pass them to `Subscribe` component (this is part of state management library I am using called [unstaded](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated)) which in turn returns render props that are then passed to my component as props.

It works fine in Debug mode, but I get error like this in Release mode

> undefined is not an object while evaluating e.state

This error from XCode debug logs.

I think something somewhere during Release build is different compared to Debug one that makes `this.props.AuthState` for example [undefined] and error is thrown when I am specifying `<Text>{AuthStore.state.username} {RouterStore.state.pathname}</Text>` where my Store props are undefined, hence I can't access their state.

I'd love to keep this Higher Order Component I made for store, as it enables really nice dev experience, but need to be able to debug what exactly breaks in release build, which thus far I was not able to do.

What optimisations are made during release build that could have effect here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer originates from: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/182#issuecomment-398052619

Issue was in accessing `value.constructor.name` where I was assuming it will always be the same as my `Container` name. During minification these change, hence it was undefined, adding unique identifier to a class resolves the issue